# How can Power BI Service consume mongodb data source?

Tags: powerbi

I want Power BI Service (not desktop) to connect to a private mongo database. I have only seen solutions using Power BI Connnector with ODBC drivers which are very poor.

Is there a better solution like direct connection to the mongo database?